# transform a list of objects into a list of integers that pass a check

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I would like to get a `List` of `Integer`s, in order, having values less than 5.

How can I do it?

```
TreeMap<String,Object> treeMap = new TreeMap<String,Object>();
HashMap<String,Object> map1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();

map1.put("a",1);
map1.put("b","2x");
map1.put("c",5);
map1.put("d",3);
map1.put("e",2);

List<Object> x = new ArrayList<>();

x = map1.values()
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toList());

x.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: and where are you stuck? where is the `TreeMap` even getting used? and avoid using `Object` for everything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as this seems as a homework question and there is little or no attempt from OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given not all the values of the map are integers, you'll need to first check whether the element is an `Integer` then map it and then check whether it's less than five and if so then print the element.

```
map1.values()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e instanceof Integer) // is this number an integer? if yes then you can pass else no
    .map(e -> (Integer)e) // map to integer so we can compare with '<' symbol
    .filter(e -> e < 5) 
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Or `.filter(e -> (e instanceof Integer) ? ((Integer) e).intValue() < 5 : false`

Comment: @daniu nice!...  or better `.filter(e -> (e instanceof Integer) && (Integer) e < 5)` but i prefer to keep things simple by using multiple intermediate operations.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the other answer didn't address part of your requirements:

> `List` of `Integer`s, in order

so I'll address that:

```
List<Integer> sortedList = 
    map1.values ()
        .stream () 
        .filter (Integer.class::isInstance) // keep only Integers
        .map (Integer.class::cast) // cast to Integer
        .filter (i -> i < 5) // keep only values < 5
        .sorted () // sort
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect into a List
System.out.println (sortedList);
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

You can also produce an `int` array instead of a `List<Integer>`:

```
int[] sortedArray = 
    map1.values ()
        .stream () 
        .filter (Integer.class::isInstance)
        .mapToInt (Integer.class::cast)
        .filter (i -> i < 5)
        .sorted ()
        .toArray();
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```